# Special characters added after cookie creation with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I try to create a cookie and when the cookie is saved, the value is not the same:

```
$id = "1";
$token = "e475c3e20898ae14c1787b71e7b787de24d31c1855bc031a6a33ca8b41ee601a";
setcookie('RememberMe_USR_Option', 'id='.$id.'&key='.$token, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 30 days
```

But when I see the cookie it's now:

```
id%3D1%26key%3De475c3e20898ae14c1787b71e7b787de24d31c1855bc031a6a33ca8b41ee601a
```

How to remove the special characters ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "extra" characters are the characters converted with the [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

To get your original value, simply decode it:

```
var_dump(urldecode($_COOKIE['RememberMe_USR_Option']));
```

Result:

```
string(73) "id=1&key=e475c3e20898ae14c1787b71e7b787de24d31c1855bc031a6a33ca8b41ee601a"
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Ok, so it's better to keep the cookie value encoded and to decode it after ?

Comment: @FAD No problem :)